# Lex Falling Through The Ceiling in Jurassic Park

Tags: jurassic-park

When Lex falls through the ceiling in Steven Spielberg's 1993 classic *Jurassic Park*, we clearly hear her screaming. However, as we hear her screaming, we do not see her mouth visually moving. How does that work? Am I missing something?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SugS3936s5g

Comment: Not really relevant to the understanding of plot, I believe that's why you're gathering downvotes. Maybe you can [edit] your question to focus more on the production aspect?

Comment: @Luciano So the downvotes are because the question isn't about plot, and the solution is to make it focus even less on plot? o.O

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica it doesn't focus on plot at all, and it's not focused on production _enough_. It has to focus on something. Also that was just my hunch, I don't know what other people's reasons are for voting.

Comment: @Luciano The question is about an aspect of production, notably the synchronisation of lips visually, with sound... specifically, why there isn't any and how that came to be.

Comment: The character is very talented at throwing their own voice, and in a deleted scene can be seen conversing with a ventriloquists' dummy regarding "the mess in the kitchen".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The actual person you see falling there is a stuntwoman; you can tell if you look closely that the actress's head doesn't quite look right; that's because it is Ariana Richards's head on the stuntwoman's body, using CG.

Sound mixing is a big part of making movies; the sound you hear throughout a movie is often not filmed as part of the same video that you are seeing. Here; the mixing of Lexi screaming is just not perfect with the video. However, you really can't see her mouth during the screams itself, so I don't think it is obvious from the sound alone that Lexi is not screaming on video at the right time.

Comment: There's a behind the scenes video where they discuss that shot.  The stunt person wasn't supposed to look up, but it was easier to fix it in post than reshoot the scene.

Answer (score -1):

Many movies have bad audio quality, it's not uncommon for the actors to re-record their dialogue for scenes where heavy sounds, background noise among other things exist to ruin hearing quality.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what this adds to the existing answer.